# (C++) Writing a database in HDF5

Tags: c++, opencv, hdf5

Hello this is my first time with HDF5, I am trying to create a database table using  a manually created dataset. The File is already created and it is deployed, however everytime I try to insert a single registry of data (everytime a cv::mat of 1x6 since I tried to insert the whole dataset and I couldn't either) I receive the following message:

H5Dwrite(): file selection+offset not within extent
    major: Dataspace
    minor: Out of range
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'H5::DataSetIException'

The code I'm using is the following

```
cv::Mat label;
int size = data.length()/n_features_objects;

size_t size_[2]={1,(hsize_t)n_features_objects};
hsize_t chunk[2]={1,(hsize_t)n_features_objects};
hsize_t max_size[2]={H5S_UNLIMITED,(hsize_t)n_features_objects};
H5::DSetCreatPropList prop;
prop.setChunk(2,chunk);
H5::DataSpace ds(2, size_,max_size);
H5::IntType datatype =  H5::PredType::NATIVE_UINT64;
objects = labelFile.createDataSet(objects_name.toStdString(),datatype, ds,prop);

//get size of the dataset
H5::DataSpace ds = objects.getSpace();
int dims = ds.getSimpleExtentNdims();
hsize_t rc [dims];
ds.getSimpleExtentDims(rc);
int rows = (int)rc[0];

for(int z=0; z<size;z++)
{
    hsize_t new_size[2]={1, (hsize_t)n_features_objects};
    labels.extend(new_size);

    cv::Mat label_oreg = cv::Mat::zeros(cv::Size(n_features_objects,1), CV_32SC1);
    //Adding data registries one by one
    label_oreg.at<int>(0,0) = label_oreg.at<int>(z,0);
    label_oreg.at<int>(0,1) = label_oreg.at<int>(z,1);
    label_oreg.at<int>(0,2) = label_oreg.at<int>(z,2);
    label_oreg.at<int>(0,3) = label_oreg.at<int>(z,3);
    label_oreg.at<int>(0,4) = label_oreg.at<int>(z,4);
    label_oreg.at<int>(0,5) = label_oreg.at<int>(z,5);

    hsize_t rows_ext[2] ={1, (hsize_t)n_features_objects};
    hsize_t offset[2] ={(hsize_t)1, 0};
    ds = labels.getSpace();
    ds.selectHyperslab(H5S_SELECT_SET,rows_ext, offset);
    H5::DataSpace mem_space(2, rows_ext);
    labels.write(label.data, H5::PredType::NATIVE_INT32, mem_space, ds);
}
```

Does anyone know what I am missing here? I think I the result is strange, since I there is always a new chunk of data registered in the dataspace in order to use it as to put the registry.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the title and description of your issue, it seems that you would like to add (i.e. append) data into an HDF5 dataset without overwriting existing data, just like a table (in a relational database) would allow you to add rows without overwriting existing ones.

If this is correct, here goes a generic example that illustrates how this can be done using [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com) in C++ (I do not know how to do it in other HDF5 C++ APIs):

```
// declare variable
unsigned long long values[6];

// create HDF5 file "my_file.h5" and use (i.e. open) it
HDFql::execute("CREATE AND USE FILE my_file.h5");

// create HDF5 dataset "my_dataset" of datatype unsigned long long (64 bit) of two dimensions (unlimited x 6)
HDFql::execute("CREATE CHUNKED(1, 6) DATASET my_dataset AS UNSIGNED BIGINT(0 TO UNLIMITED, 6)");

// register variable "values" for subsequent use (by HDFql)
HDFql::variableRegister(values);

// keep reading data (from hypothetical function "read") and store it in variable "values" until there is no more to read
while(read(values))
{
    // extend first dimension of dataset "my_dataset" one unit
    HDFql::execute("ALTER DIMENSION my_dataset TO +1");

    // insert (i.e. write) content of variable "values" into the last position of the first dimension of dataset "my_dataset" (thanks to a hyperslab selection)
    HDFql::execute("INSERT INTO my_dataset[-1:1:1:1] VALUES FROM MEMORY 0");
}

// unregister variable "values" as it is no longer used/needed (by HDFql)
HDFql::variableUnregister(values);
```

Comment: Thanks @SOG for the example. You are right, however this is code that I am modifying from an already existing one.